# Added TButton won't align with previous TButtons after upgrade from 10.3.1 to 10.3.3 in Android

Tags: android, button, alignment, firemonkey

I'm using `FireMonkey` to create my Android application.

I have 6 `TButtons` on a panel and want to insert a 7th.  The 6 were positioned under CX 10.3.1  on an android device.  I recently upgraded to CX 10.3.3, and wanted to insert a 7th `TButton` in that row -- there is room -- but the installed result on the android device has an older button and the new one stepping on each other.  I then tried to take the end (old) `TButton` and place it below the row of 6 and put the new `TButton` where the old one was and align the row using `Space equally` and I still get a mess.

Has there been a change in buttons?  The new button is from the `Standard` Palette.  It has been a while since I wrote the original code, but was there a FireMonkey based `TButton` before that I should be using?  And if so, where is it located?

Any help would sure be appreciated.

Comment: It is not possible to answer your question without some more information. Let's start with the following. 1) What values for what properties of the 7th button have you set in the designer? (copy the relevant part, the parent panel incl. the buttons), from the `.fmx`) 2) What `align` settings do the existing 6 buttons have? 3) do you modify any of `Position`, `Align`, `Margins`, `Padding` or `Size` in code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Tom.  I've been doing a lot of trial and error testing and still getting odd results. Been wondering if it is related to this.  The device is a SM-T813, and it is getting correctly picked up.  But on the design page, under "view" , it only lists templates for Android tablets  3.5, 4,5, 7 and 10".   the T813 is a 9,7" tablet.  Can I load an Android 9.7" tablet template?   BTW, the .fmx files show the correct placements on the template, but that isn't what is loaded on the device.

Comment: What? I asked you to provide additional information regarding the buttons on the panel, as I know that aligning controls can behave seemingly erratic. I asked you to provide that information, so I could check whether that could be the reason. Will you please respond to my request?

Comment: The stackoverflow editor doesn't appear to let you put files or longer msgs on it.  Finally found the problem, though-- a chunk of code to handle a previous problem that changed the buttons positions--thanks to your clue.    This stackoverflow forum isn't as friendly as to adding code and stuff needed for getting help, compared to say, 
forums.embarcadero.com     Any hints on that?     Again, thanks for your help.